# рассчитать рост месячных продаж по стране в процентах по данному датафрейму

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Прошу помощи с решением интересной задачи, к которой мне не удается найти решение. Если кратко переходить к сути, то задача следующая:

- Некое предприятие продает товары покупающим из различных стран. Выяснить, в какой из них был самый большой процентный рост месячных продаж. Выяснить, сколько процентов составляет данный рост. В расчет следует брать именно те страны, в которых были ненулевые продажи в обоих этих месяцах.

Датафрейм выглядит соответственно:
( берутся два месяца - 9 и 3 месяца 2011 года )

| InvoiceNo | StockCode | Quantity | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice | CustomerID | Country | Price | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 536365 | 85123A | 6 | 2010-12-01 08:26:00 | 2.55 | 17850 | United Kingdom | 15.30 | 2011 | 9 |
| 536365 | 71053 | 6 | 2010-12-01 08:26:00 | 3.39 | 17850 | United Kingdom | 20.34 | 2011 | 9 |
| 581587 | 23254 | 4 | 2011-12-09 12:50:00 | 4.15 | 12860 | France | 16.60 | 2011 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 581587 | 23255 | 4 | 2011-12-09 12:50:00 | 4.15 | 12860 | France | 16.60 | 2011 | 3 |
| 581587 | 22138 | 3 | 2011-12-09 12:50:00 | 4.95 | 12860 | France | 14.85 | 2011 | 3 |
| 581588 | 22380 | 9 | 2011-12-09 12:52:00 | 2.10 | 12594 | Italy | 18.90 | 2011 | 3 |
| 581588 | 22381 | 9 | 2011-12-09 12:52:00 | 2.10 | 12594 | Italy | 18.90 | 2011 | 3 |

Примерное решение данной задачи в моей голове примерно такое - по каждой из стран рассчитать количество покупок в одном из каждых месяцев и затем просчитать, насколько за эти месяца увеличилось или уменьшилось количество покупок, т.е. измерить в процентах.
( к примеру, в 3 месяце в стране Norway было совершено 10 покупок, а в 9 месяце уже 100, прирост составил 400 и так посчитать к каждой стране и вывести страну с самым большим приростом )

Возможно, мое решение к данной задаче неверно, и так же я не знаю как превратить это решение в код, поэтому я прошу вашей помощи с решением данной задачи.

мой код к задаче неверен:

```
months_march = purchases.loc[(purchases['Year'] == 2011) & (purchases['Month'] == 3)]
months_september = purchases.loc[(purchases['Year'] == 2011) & (purchases['Month'] == 9)]
months = months_september.append(months_march)
months['Percent'] = months['Price'].pct_change().mul(100).round(0).map(lambda x: '{0:g}'.format(x) if x==x else x)
first = months.sort_values('Percent', ascending=False)[['Country', 'Percent']]
first = first.values.tolist()
first[0]
```

как ответ, должно получиться что то в роде этого:

> Norway, 586

[image: датафрейм выглядит вот так]

Comment: вас интересует рост месячных продаж по покупкам или по деньгам? можно купить 1 за млн$ или 200к по 1$. данные с таблицы брать?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте примерно так (это решение не тестировалось):

```
(df.groupby(['Country','Year','Month'])
     .agg({'Price':'sum'})
     .reset_index()
     .groupby(['Country','Year'])
     .apply(
         lambda x: x['Price']
         .pct_change()
         .mul(100)
         .round()
         .max()
     ).sort_values(ascending=False)
     .head(1))
```